# Python: ggplot geom_histogram() binwidth or bin parameter missing?

Tags: python, visualization, ggplot2

I am unable to change number of bins when using geom_histogram() function. There is nothing in the documention, except some examples where binwidth=X is used (which is how R:ggplot2 uses it). However, this parameter seems to have no effect on the actual output.

Version: ggplot 0.10.4, Python 3.5 64bit

So for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
dataframe['column'].plot.hist(bins=30)
plt.show()
```

works as expected and draws 30 bins. Meanwhile:

```
from ggplot import *
gg = ggplot(dataframe, aes(x='column')) + geom_histogram(binwidth=300)
print(gg)
```

does not change number of bins (I understand that binwidth sets interval for one bin), and have tried multiple values and/or datasets

Comment: Never used ggplot in python. But in R, you want to use `geom_histogram(bins=30)`, not `binwidth`, which refers to the width of each bin and cannot be used in combination with `bins`. (By default, `bins=30` by the way,)

Comment: As Python's ggplot is built on top on matplotlib I would expect that bins=X parameter should be working but it is not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

bins=10 parameter is actually added in latest version (ggplot 0.11) https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/513